# Storing lots of small web pages on Android

Tags: android

I'm developing an application that uses about 150 small HTML pages (up to 25-30kb, actively used by WebView).

My question is how to save this kind of data on Android device ?

Maybe XML or SQLite......

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all the pages in **Assets** folder. They will be packed together in the apk and access them as below:

```
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/your_html_page.html");
```

Comment: How will that affect the size of my .apk file ?

Comment: Of course, your apk size will increase too depending on the amount of pages and their size

Comment: Can I addd files to assets at runtime ?

Comment: No, assets are compiled with the APK and they are part of it.

Comment: You cant edit resources (assets, raw, layout, etc.) once they are packaged inside .apk

Comment: Is there any way to compress this pages or to do something to decrease their size ?

Comment: If your file doesnt end with any of these extensions **(".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png", ".gif",
    ".wav", ".mp2", ".mp3", ".ogg", ".aac",
    ".mpg", ".mpeg", ".mid", ".midi", ".smf", ".jet",
    ".rtttl", ".imy", ".xmf", ".mp4", ".m4a",
    ".m4v", ".3gp", ".3gpp", ".3g2", ".3gpp2",
    ".amr", ".awb", ".wma", ".wmv")** then you are good to go, because the android will compress it automatically

Answer (score 0):

You can write them at runtime into a specific directory in the sdcard (if present) and load them from it when you want...